# Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error on Chrome browser

Tags: django, reactjs, google-chrome, npm, manifest.json

I have a react app that built through npm run build. GET and POST request from the front-end to back-end gives status 200 but I am getting a weird error that may cause all the images from my files not appear on localhost.

I have already tried to reinstall node, added 'manifest_version': 2 as it is the current version of chrome manifest.

[Click here for inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzNo8.png)

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. 
Below is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Django React Boilerplate</title>
    <link href="/static/css/2.87ad9c80.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        ! function(l) {
            function e(e) {
                for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], f = 0, i = []; f < n.length; f++) t = n[f], p[t] && i.push(p[t][0]), p[t] = 0;
                for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]);
                for (s && s(e); i.length;) i.shift()();
                return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a()
            }

            function a() {
                for (var e, r = 0; r < c.length; r++) {
                    for (var t = c[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) {
                        var u = t[o];
                        0 !== p[u] && (n = !1)
                    }
                    n && (c.splice(r--, 1), e = f(f.s = t[0]))
                }
                return e
            }
            var t = {},
                p = {
                    1: 0
                },
                c = [];

            function f(e) {
                if (t[e]) return t[e].exports;
                var r = t[e] = {
                    i: e,
                    l: !1,
                    exports: {}
                };
                return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f), r.l = !0, r.exports
            }
            f.m = l, f.c = t, f.d = function(e, r, t) {
                f.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
                    enumerable: !0,
                    get: t
                })
            }, f.r = function(e) {
                "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                    value: "Module"
                }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                })
            }, f.t = function(r, e) {
                if (1 & e && (r = f(r)), 8 & e) return r;
                if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r;
                var t = Object.create(null);
                if (f.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
                        enumerable: !0,
                        value: r
                    }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r)
                    for (var n in r) f.d(t, n, function(e) {
                        return r[e]
                    }.bind(null, n));
                return t
            }, f.n = function(e) {
                var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                    return e.default
                } : function() {
                    return e
                };
                return f.d(r, "a", r), r
            }, f.o = function(e, r) {
                return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
            }, f.p = "/";
            var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [],
                n = r.push.bind(r);
            r.push = e, r = r.slice();
            for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) e(r[o]);
            var s = n;
            a()
        }([])
    </script>
    <script src="/static/js/2.e5ee7667.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.9f678b97.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It appeared that the error starts from the beginning of my index.html file.

Comment: where did you host your application? I had this same error once, then at the end found out that it was because I turned on the IAP on the GCP that blocked it from loading correctly.

Comment: I am using django manage.py runserver script. Hosting my web on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. And I also have CORS enabled.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @zixuan check the link above for screenshot. And it's the title of my question.

Comment: Maybe instead do `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: @zixuan I tried <!DOCTYPE html>. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I updated my React app to be served from a subdirectory. I updated the image links to `src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'PATH_TO_IMAGE'}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758001/manifest-is-not-valid-json-line-1-column-1-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem when I moved my Codesandbox project to local. In my case, there was no `manifest.json` file in the `public` folder.
I solved it by adding the default `manifest.json` that `create-react-app` generates:

```
{
  "short_name": "CloseWeUI",
  "name": "The front-end UI for CloseWe",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that was my problem. I didn't push my public folder onto Heroku.

Answer (score 19):

As I added password protection to a developer-only page of mine, I suddenly started getting "manifest line 1 column 1 syntax error" (manifest.json) errors.

I am also using AWS Amplify as well as Create React App to build my app. I tried all of the solutions above, but nothing helped.

The one thing that did help was adding one property to the link to my manifest.json in my index.html.

To solve this, I added `crossorigin="use-credentials"`*, like below:

```
<link crossorigin="use-credentials" rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
```

Comment: It works for me, just add this line to the beginning of index.html

Comment: Superb, works. Is there a security concern with adding `crossorigin="use-credentials"`?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem ("Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error") while running my app (react app with react-router, published with AWS Amplify).

My problem was fixed by doing the following:
In "Rewrites and redirects" make sure you have "json" in the following line:

```
Source address:
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|json|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>

Target address:
/index.html

Type:
200 (Rewrite)
```

The above solution also fixed problem with non-working react-router links in production as it was reported in the following thread:
[React Router DOM not working correctly on Amplify Console AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449853/react-router-dom-not-working-correctly-on-amplify-console-aws)

Here is to my personal project with fixed manifest.json issue, as well as non-working react-router issue (a link to some random code snippet - fibonacci memoization in this case):

https://everhint.com/hintlink/algorithms/javascript/codesnippet/fibonacci/memoization/fibonacci-memoization/d01f275b-6acf-4f26-9448-e99939c9d4b7.html

Answer (score 6):

VladS answer solved my problem.
I was also using AWS Amplify Console for my Angular App.

You can also have a look at the Content-Type in the response headers of your manifest file. It should NOT be `text/html`. If it is, you have to change your server configuration to serve the file in the right Content-Type. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342679/2397787)

Angular names the Manifest-File "manifest.webmanifest".
So I also had to go to the "Rewrites and redirects" Page in the Amplify Console and edited the existing entry like so:

```
Source address
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|json|webmanifest)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

(I added **json|webmanifest**)

Answer (score 5):

**React create app**

If you got this error while working with React Create App you should go to:
*public/index.html* find `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />` and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

in line 7 of index.html just delete this

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

the error is coming from this line cause you delete manifest.json but you forget this line so you have an error in your console

Answer (score 1):

you should put

```
 "homepage": "",
```

on your **packaje.json**.
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i put the manifest.json on the public file with the index.html [image]

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to be a catchall error for a lot of issues.  For me the issue was using http-server to load the page.  When I switched to the project root directory and ran `npm start` , the project loaded without issues and any changes.

Answer (score 0):

**I deleted this line from my index.html file in the public directory**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```