# React Router DOM not working correctly on Amplify Console AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I have deployed react app on Amplify Console following their documentation. The site is deployed and running fine, I am able to navigate using links but when I try to land to any url directly I get redirected to my configured 404 page.

Below is the code I am using

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

And here is how my route looks like -

```
<Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={(): JSX.Element => <Home auth={this.auth} />}
    />
    <Route path="/features" render={(): JSX.Element => <Features />} />
    <Route
      path="/pagenotfound"
      render={(): JSX.Element => <PageNotFound />}
    />
    <Redirect from="/**" to="/pagenotfound" />
</Switch>
```

Here is the link to the app - https://master.dkf0zemoh330o.amplifyapp.com/features

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This happens because navigating directly to a path or reloading a path requests that path on the *server*, but React Router can only control routes on the *client*.

I was able to work around that limitation with Amplify using **redirect settings**, as mentioned in these two GitHub issues:

- [Amplify Console 200 (Rewrite) fails on SPA React (Router) Application #2498](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2498#issuecomment-454565081)
- [Amplify console is not building my react frontend code correctly ? #1326](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1326#issuecomment-485923845).

From the Amplify console, you can access the **Rewrites and redirects** menu item in left sidebar. From there you can update the redirect rule to these settings:

```
Source address: </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>
Target address: /index.html
Type: 200
```

This uses their regex source feature that matches problematic routes and redirects them to `index.html`. You may need to replace this default route with `/` or something else depending on how your app is structured. Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you - implemented this on my app and can confirm it's working as expected.

Comment: Also added it to my app that uses facebook login and AWS cognito redirecting to myDomain.com/userProfile, and it's working fine

Comment: Why does this give me a `502 Error`?

Comment: Make sure you have the leading slash in `/index.html` or you'll get a `502` from CloudFront.  That's the problem I ran into at least.

Comment: WTF..... I spent hours and this worked for me. Thank you. I was pulling my hair out

Answer (score 4):

Thanks!
I would add also |json| the string - it fixes "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error on Chrome browser" problem:

[Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error on Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423244/manifest-line-1-column-1-syntax-error-on-chrome-browser/59688942#59688942)

Comment: Hi VladS. Where would you put the |json| in the string?

Comment: In AWS Amplify go to: All apps -> 
MySuperCoolApp -> App settings: Rewrites and redirects -> Edit. Then add rule: [ </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|json|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/> ]   [ /index.html ] [ 200(rewrite) ] (remove square brackets)

Answer (score 2):

If the steps above don't fully work try adding `<base href="/" />` to the `<head/>` section of your index.html as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/59#issuecomment-632988536), sadly this took a while to find.

For a complete answer this is my final "Rewrites and redirects" opened in the text editor:

```json
[
    {
        "source": "https://example.com",
        "target": "https://www.example.com",
        "status": "302",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|webp|html|xml|webmanifest|mp4)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```