# "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error"

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-web-app-service, manifest

I'm using Vue.js to create a Progressive Web Application (PWA) as a school project.
Whenever I host the website with Azure I get "`Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error`". 
I don't have this problem on localhost …

[Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools) responds with :

```
/manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
manifest.json:1 GET https://serviceworkerspike.azurewebsites.net/manifest.json 404
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

#### How can I correct the error?

---

I have the following line in my `index.html` :

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Here is my `manifest.json` file :

```json
{
  "name": "MessageBoardUCN",
  "short_name": "MessageBoardUCN",
  "theme_color": "#ff095a",
  "background_color": "#feaaee",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

##### What I have tried

- Using lower-case letters in the `name` and `short_name` properties – `messageboarducn`.
- Setting `starturl` to the hosted URL or to "/".
- Moving the `manifest.json` file to the root directory or to the `src/` directory, but other guides told me it should be in the same folder as `index.html`, and `public/` is the default for that.

[This is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTLph.png).

The hosted URL, https://serviceworkerspike.azurewebsites.net, doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Possibly related: [Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33758001).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the exact same problem (on an Azure Windows Web Service). I just created a new web.config in the root folder with the following content (or edit the existing, if there is one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This adds the mime configuration for json-files.

Comment: I also facing same error where as I am using node js, bootstrap and tomcat server. I created web.config file same as above but no luck. Is there any other reason ?

Comment: @kodali Are you sure that you are running IIS?

Comment: Yes. I am running on IIS server.

Comment: @kodali And you get the exact same error? And not on localhost?

Comment: Yes, It is working fine in localhost, but not on IIS Server.

Comment: @kodali If you still get a 404 in your browser, it would seem as if your Tomcat-server isn't properly configured. Check out these links:
https://www.developershome.com/wap/wapServerSetup/tutorial.asp?page=settingUpMIME
https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-231245.html

Comment: I tried in another server, which is not IIS but tomcat configured properly (means other apps running). But my app shows same error.

Comment: same problem. this change in web.config solved it thanks !

Answer (score 44):

If your manifest file is at the root level (where your index.html file is placed) you can reference it like the following in the `<head>` tag of your index.html file:

```
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="manifest.json"/>
```

Plus the `startUrl` property in the manifest file should have the value:

`"start_url": "/"`

as you target the root as starting point.

Otherwise, if you would serve your app with a specific base URL, you should reflect it in the property value:

```
Example: 

Considering -->  www.myapp.com/my-other-url-part/

Use:
    "start_url": "/my-other-url-part/"

Or simply:
    "start_url": "./"   <-- This would match any base-href != "/"
```

You should then set your web server to automatically serve the index.html file (this is often enabled per default)

Comment: I still get the same mistake but my index.html and manifest isn't in the root, it's in a folder /public as that's how Vue set it up. I linked a photo of my file structure in the question

Answer (score 17):

For me it was so simple to fix , just a matter of code orgnizing in the index.html , the following link tag has to be on top of the few copied from the favicon generator , just bellow the meta tags

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

Comment: Working with React & create-react-app, that solves the issue!

Answer (score 7):

`<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`remove this line from the index.html header file
or create the manifest.json file inside the public directory

Answer (score 5):

I understand you are using Azure cloud but I used to have the same issue using **AWS Amplify** and here are my steps to solve it.

1. Go to your [Amplify console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/)
2. Select the application that shows the issue.
3. In the left panel  select the option titled **Rewrites and redirects**.
4. You will find there the redirection rules of your application. Please select the option **Edit**.
5. Find the row with this structure

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`.

6. Add the extension **webmanifest** after `json`. The code would look like

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|webmanifest)$)([^.]+$)/>`.

7. Press **Save** and inspect the site again.

---

If your project use Apache, then edit the file **.htacces** and include the **webmanifest** extension in the section:

```html
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js|webmanifest)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://your-url"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I guess this configuration helps to avoid unwanted and malicious extensions.

Comment: This is the right answer if you are using AWS Amplify! Thanks a lot. By the way, you need to add this "Rewrites and redirects" setting in Amplify console. Otherwise, you will get AccessDenied error when refreshing a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I had to have two things configured:

1. `%PUBLIC_URL%` in the href of the manifest in index.html:

   `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`
2. Configure `homepage` in package.json to the directory where your app will live:

   `"homepage": "https://example.com/myapp",`

Answer (score 0):

Check the manifest file format. When I had UNIX / Unicode UTF-8 no BOM I got this error. After change to DOS / Unicode UTF-8 no BOM the error was gone. The file format can be checked and changed in any advanced code editor. I don't know exactly what was the problem, probably depends on your hosting company. I compared the files in hexa editor and they visually seemed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by adding json mimetype to the webconfig.   The asp.net code was not allowing mimeType json by default to be served.

```
<system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it solved. In my app.js express backend folder I put index.html file by mistake

**(app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../frontend/build/***index.html***")))
**

so after removing its working fine. Code should like below

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../frontend/build")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"../frontend/build/index.html"));
});
}

Answer (score 0):

[A typical manifest file includes information about the app name, icons it should use, the start_url it should start at when launched, and more. It is often used by favicon generators for websites.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBPSv.png)

For some reason, this file `site.webmanifest` may be blocked by your web server or CDN. I still haven’t figured what it causing this issue though there is a simple workaround. Just rename `site.webmanifest` to `manifest.json` and update your link tag.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/manifest.json">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing these same issues when I am working in the Firebase notification service,
I accidentally put `Manifest.Json` File on out of the src folder.
please make sure the manifest json file is on `src/manifest.json`.
then the error is gone.

If you work any of the project, this error only come for wrong path of `manifest.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using nextjs with the app directory, for me it was just a matter of me putting the `manifest` file on the wrong place, I had to put it on the `public` folder insted of the `root` folder. That solved the issue for me.

```
project

└───app
│   ...your app...
│   
└───public
    │   manifest.json
```

And the link should look like this:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
```

Comment: I did this and I still get the same issue in next 14

Answer (score 0):

> #### *How can I correct the error?*

– I cannot reproduce the error as you describe it.
But I got this error when I downloaded [a *Create React App* from CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-vs-vanilla-demo-uc08fv) – in a setting completely unrelated to Microsoft Azure. <sup>1</sup>

I found two ways to get rid of the error, of which I prefer the first below.

#### 1. Stop using `manifest.json`

In `index.html`, remove (or comment out) the reference to `manifest.json`. <sup>2</sup>

In my case, the line to remove is :

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
```

Also, delete the `manifest.json` file – if there was one to begin with. <sup>3</sup>

#### 2. Alternatively, in `manifest.json`, set *any* property

In my case, I didn't even have a  `manifest.json` file.
Creating one, and setting *any* property in it, silenced the error :

```
{"any_property": "Any string here"}
```

Even empty strings solved it.
The following `manifest.json` also silenced the error :

```
{"": ""}
```

You haven't provided any means to reproduce the error.
This makes it hard to tell why you get it.

This second solution works for me, but not for you.
In fact, the exact `manifest.json` you've provided solves it for me. <sup>4</sup>

### References

- [Possible duplicate of the question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57423244)
- [A *Create React App* at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-vs-vanilla-demo-uc08fv)
- [Example project that reproduces the error](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/StackOverflow-Q59068699/59068699.zip)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The error is reproduced in [this project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-vs-vanilla-demo-uc08fv).
Just download, unzip, install by running `npm install`, and then `npm start` to run the project. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the error.
The error appears only in a Chromium/Blink browser, not in Firefox/Gecko.

<sup>2</sup>
In [the example project](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/StackOverflow-Q59068699/59068699.zip), `index.html` is in the `public` directory.

<sup>3</sup>
The `manifest.json` file is *optional* for a progressive web app (PWA) if I'm not mistaken. 
However, [the manifest *is* mandatory](https://techglimpse.com/pwa-essentials-manifest-file-explained-mandatory-attributes) in a Chromium browser if you want to [enable the installation of the PWA within its user interface on a mobile or desktop device](https://web.dev/customize-install).

<sup>4</sup>
All I needed to do was to delete the `icons` property – as I don't have your icons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what solved it for me was placing the manifest in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

In file {site.webmanifest} remove the "/" from the image link and try again. I did this and it worked.!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Check your base should be like this `<base href=""/>`

Comment: I had to use ./ for my href value like - `<base href="./">` in index.html and set `"index": "/route/from/domain/index.html"` in ngsw-config.json for mine to work. Just same for `"start_url": "./"`

Answer (score -2):

**You can comment this line in index.html. Thanks me later.**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
```

**Note**: manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
homescreen on Android.