# How to change manifest.json content-type in a Vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very simple Vue app and when I add the manifest.json file it says in the console `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` Now I have searched for this error and it looks I have wrong what an another user in SO in a similar question talks about:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342679/10708260

Indeed in my network tab of the *devtools* in manifest.json appears: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" instead of "Content-Type: application/json" as the user says.

However I have search how to change this but i´ve only found solutions with people using a custom client for their http requests, but not just for a simple Vue app generated with the Vue Cli tool like mine.

Also if you think my problem might other thing be welcome to comment , please.

Comment: So you're saying this is a serverless setup?

Comment: Yes, by the moment this app doesn´t have anything in the 'backend' but just the Vue-Cli serving

Comment: So I just sorted it out, I installed the vue-pwa plugin and I moved the manifest.json inside the public folder, and the content-type instantly changed to json